# Java: Making System.out.println() argument span multiple lines?

Tags: java

I have the following message:

```
System.out.println("Players take turns marking a square. Only squares not already marked can be picked. Once a player has marked three squares in a row, he or she wins! If all squares are marked and no three squares are the same, a tied game is declared. Have Fun!");
```

This is a very long message and streaks across my screen, I want to break it up into segments so it does not break the design flow of my code. When I press enter though, Java no longer interprets the line as a string; Java believes it is a separate statement. How can I make Java interpret multiline print statements?

Comment: And also use StringBuilder to construct this message 'cause it would streak across the source viewer (IDE etc.) sceen as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String line = "Information and stuff" + 
          "More information and stuff " + 
          "Even more information and stuff";

System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Is there some kind of generator online that will print out multi-line code samples as as String and print them with proper indenting, etc.? **Update:** It looks like IntelliJ will preserve the formatting with a simple copy-paste.

Answer (score 7):

Following Java's coding conventions:

```
System.out.println("Players take turns marking a square. "
                   + "Only squares not already marked can be picked. "
                   + "Once a player has marked three squares in a row, "
                   + "he or she wins! If all squares are marked and no "
                   + "three squares are the same, a tied game is declared. "
                   + "Have Fun!");
```

Always break with the concatenation operator to start the next line for readability.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#248

Answer (score 2):

You can type: System.out.println("This is the first line \n" + "This is the second line")

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Players take turns marking a square."
+ "\nOnly squares not already marked can be picked."
+ "\nOnce a player has marked three squares in a row, he or she wins!"
+ "\nIf all squares are marked and no three squares are the same, a tied game is declared."
+ "\nHave Fun!");
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

add '\n' where ever you want a new line.

Comment: geez. i apologize. read it in a rush and replied quickly. my bad.